# System.Web.Mvc.HttpPostAttribute vs System.Web.Http.HttpPostAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, http-post

In my Web API project which is based on the ASP.NET MVC, I want to use the `HttpPost` attribute. When I've added that onto the action, The IntelliSense suggests me these two namespaces:

- **System.Web.Mvc.HttpPostAttribute**
- **System.Web.Http.HttpPostAttribute**

Which one should be used and why?

Answer (score 10):

Prior to ASP.NET Core, MVC and WebAPI were mainly separate libraries.

The .Mvc namespace applies to MVC controllers, the .Http namespace to Web API controllers.